# Sum of users do not match what is displayed in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I do not know if it is a mistake, but I did a test here in Google Analytics.

I went to `Public > Overview`, I ran from `09/12/2018` to `11/12/2018`. I add the 'points' and in the end gave the result of `106 users`, however, just below the graph appears the total, and he reports `102 users`.

```
Detailing:
09/12 - 36 users
10/12 - 34 users
11/12 - 36 users
Total: 106 users.
```

[image: Print here]

Is it a bug in the Google Analytics report?

I'm using the Google Analytics API to show the access reports inside the client administration panel, the results reported by the API are correct adding the sum, already on the platform of Google Analytics itself there is this divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a bug. users are reported as the number of users for the whole time period. So if user a user had two visits on 09/12 and 10/12 she would be reported as 1 user for each daily row but only as 1 user for the whole period row

as [from API docs:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_users)
ga:users
UI Name: Users
The total number of users for the **requested time period.**

Comment: Understood. Thank you